# Using Custom Push Broadcast Receiver in Android

Tags: android, pushwoosh

According to the guide posted [here](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/android-faq#using-custom-push-broadcast-receiver-in-android) I'm trying to implement my own BroadCastReceiver but in the `PushManager` class, there doesn't seem to be `preHandlePush()` and `postHandlePush()` defined. Am I using some outdated version of the library which I took from [here](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-android-sdk)? or am I missing something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update the guide (http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/android-faq#using-custom-push-broadcast-receiver-in-android), please take a look. These functions were moved to **PushManagerImpl** class.

i.e.

```
Bundle pushBundle = PushManagerImpl.preHandlePush(context, intent);
```

Comment: Yep, after meddling around I found out them my self and went ahead with development. I was too busy to update here. Thanks anyways.